# Criteria for accessing R packages?

Tags: security, package, rstudio, rstudio-server

As an IT administrator, what criteria should I use when approving an R package to be installed into my environment?

Currently, RStudio users (non-IT focused) have full access to download and install any package. I understand why this is a problem... but if I restricted access a custom whitelist of existing packages, users will eventually ask for new packages, and I'll have no way to assess whether the package appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no R-specific knowledge, but I would say that, like any software that users are bringing into your organization, you should include some measure of "Pedigree and progeny"; ie where did it come from, and does it have a good reputation.

Ultimately it should be up to the users requesting the software to do the leg-work, so in addition on the request form, I would include some questions like this to nudge people to do the due-diligence themselves:

- Where is the package hosted (where did you download it from)?
- Is it a well-used and well-known package?
- (probably doesn't apply to R: is the software project still maintained and does it release regular security patches. Are there open CVE vulnerabilities against it?)
- If you are unsure of the above, have you opened the source code to check that it appears to be doing what it claims to?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what environment the other users are working in. Do your general users have access to the production server, or are they doing development on their local machines? If they have production access and are doing development there, you may have bigger issues related to overall change management. More information about who has access to do what could help us give a more detailed answer.

In general though, it's good to have an approval process or documentation for any packages used in production; that way if you run into issues later you can determine the last change made (e.g. plyr and dplyr conflicts breaking scripts).

The approval process can be as simple as:

- Request date
- Name of individual making request
- New package requested (name and version)
- Purpose of new package
- Any other relevant information

As the administrator, if you trust the users you can simply sign off on the request and install the package (or let them install it). To add another layer of security, you could google the package and make sure it's legit before signing off.

You could also take the route of restricting package downloads to the CRAN repository. It's not perfect, but you're relying on a slightly more curated list.